# An interesting sequence limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence $\{a_i\}_{0}^{\infty}$ is defined as below:

> $a_0 = 1$, and for $i \geq 1$, let $a_i = \text{ The smallest integer j } > a_{i-1} \text{ such that for every k } \leq \lfloor \sqrt{j} \rfloor ,  a^{-1}_{j-k^2}\text{exists}$

One olympiad question was proving that the sequence is infinite, it's trivial to prove by contradiction.

Now, I was experimenting with the density function, i.e the probability of taking a number not exceeding $i$ and it being a member of the sequence:

> $$\displaystyle \rho_i := \frac{\#\{a_j | a_j \leq i\}}{i}$$

I wrote a python code (you can use it [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/MHNqbgV1)), and computed upto $4*10^6$, and the density showed a graph similar to $$\rho_x \approx^?a \frac{log(x)}{x^.6}$$ (where $a$ is an constant)

> Is the approximation to $\rho_x$ correct ? What is a better approximation to $\rho_x$ ?

Comment: Why the downvotes ?

Comment: The title is misleading. Your question is about density, not limit.

Comment: What is $$a^{-1}_{j-k^2}\ ?$$ What does the condition $$a^{-1}_{j-k^2}\ \text{exists}$$ mean?

Comment: Unrelated: Please stop bumping this question to the front page using fake edits.